# Pyspark with AWS Glue join on multiple columns creating duplicates

Tags: amazon-web-services, join, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have two tables in AWS Glue, table_1 and table_2 that have almost identical schemas, however, table_2 has two additional columns. I am trying to join these two tables together on the columns that are the same and add the columns that are unique to table_2 with null values for the "old" data whose schema does not include those values.

Currently, I am able to join the two tables, using something similar to:

```
joined_table = Join.apply(table_1, table_2, 'id', 'id')
```

where the first 'id' is the id column in table_1 and the second 'id' is the id column in table_2. This call successfully joins the table into one, however, the resulting joined_table has duplicate fields for the matching columns.

My two questions are:

1. How can I leverage AWS Glue job with Pyspark to join all columns that match across the two tables so that there are not duplicate columns and while adding the new fields?
2. This sample call only takes in the 'id' column as I was trying to get this just to work, however, I want to pass in all the columns that match across the two tables. How can I pass in a list of columns to this Join.apply call? I am aware of the available methods from Pyspark directly, however, am wondering if there is a way specific to AWS Glue jobs or if there is something I need to do within AWS Glue to leverage Pyspark functionality directly.

Answer (score 4):

I found that I needed to rename the columns in table_1 and then was missing a call to .drop_fields after my Join.apply call to remove the old columns from the joined table.

Additionally, you can pass in a list of column names rather than the single 'id' column that I was trying to use in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 joineddata = Join.apply(frame1 = table1, frame2 = table2, keys1 = ['id'], keys2 = ['id'], transformation_ctx = 'joinedData')
```

The join in aws glue doesn't handle duplicates. You need to convert to dataframes and then drop duplicate.

If you have duplicates, Try this:

```
selectedFieldsDataFrame = joineddata.toDF()
selectedFieldsDataFrame.dropDuplicates()
```